# How can I help my client select a Wordpress template for an intranet?

Tags: wordpress, templates, intranet, extranet

I have to put an extranet on the Wordpress CMS for a non-IT professional.
He told me he wants a community intranet for his clients.

I researched on the web and found three templates which can meet his needs: [Thrive](https://themeforest.net/item/thrive-intranet-community-wordpress-theme/12275020), [Woffice](https://woffice.io/) and [Alliance](https://themeforest.net/item/alliance-intranet-extranet-wordpress-theme/12087162).

But I don't really know how I can choose between them. It seems they can make same things and I need help to take my decision.

How can I find the advantages and drawbacks of them?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately your question is very opinion based and isn't really suitable for a Q and A style site. The best I can suggest is installing all 3 themes (or finding demos of them online) and testing them out to see which are easiest to use and offer the best documentation for your client.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for that quick answer, i don't really understand what you mean by "isn't really suitable for a Q and A style site". Do you mean there is no answer which work for all situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Good work!

Ultimately, you cannot know for sure without embarking on the implementation, so it is a case of reducing the risk. If it becomes clear the selection you've made isn't working, you can switch to an alternative with relatively little disruption.

I suggest you take the role of advisor and work with your client to decide. Summarise your findings, prepare a presentation in which you demonstrate each template (even if just the demo mode on the theme site) and listen to their feedback.

If you are looking for people with direct experience of implementing Wordpress intranets who may have been through the same process, try some of the intranet groups on LinkedIn.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry, i'm late to answer...
Thank you, we finaly buy Woffice and it works well !